# SO tag-editor calculating width of input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a similar tag editor like SO and it's working pretty well i must say. The only thing that is giving me some problems is calculating the width of the textbox after a user selected a tag.

With every tag a user adds i recalculate the width of the input field next to it but i can't seem to get it right.

I have 2 divs next to eachother. The left div contains the tags, the right div contains the input field.

Can someone tell me how SO does it or tell me how i could calculate the width of a div? 
(Assume the div with the tag only holds plain text + the delete tag image)

**Edit:**

I have the complete editor working in a similar way as SO does it. The only thing i am struggling with is resizing the input field after a user added a tag (or removed one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you might be looking for, albeit very simple:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/z2WBx/3/)

It just uses the image within the tag to store the delete button, and has a slight margin to keep some space between the text and the image. The tags are floated to stay away from each other as well.

**You can find the classes that SO uses for it's buttons by checking out the source:**

```
.post-tag, .post-text .post-tag, .wmd-preview a.post-tag {
    color: #3E6D8E;
    background-color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
    border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

a.post-tag:hover, .post-text a.post-tag:hover, .wmd-preview a.post-tag:hover {
    background-color: #3E6D8E;
    color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
    border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**You should be able to get the widths by using jQuery or javascript:**

```
//jQuery
var width = $('#yourTag').width(); //or $(this).width();

//javascript
var tag = document.getElementById('yourTag');
var width = tag.width  // or tag.clientWidth
```

Comment: @Jeroen, do you have any source or possibly an example (jsfiddle). If you want to calculate the width of a div, that should be able to be done easily with javascript or jQuery. Ala - $('.tag:last').width()

Comment: Using .width() helps yes. it's not perfect, i still have to add a bit to it but at least the input field stopped breaking to the next line.

Comment: You might have to adjust it slightly to make up for any padding or extra margins.

Comment: You don´t need to calculate the width, i guess. Set div#tags_container  white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; This tag editor is pretty complex!

Answer (score 1):

Well you know your initial widths and if you wrap the tags you add inside a `<span>` or something like that, you can get the width of that tag. So every time you add a tag you substract the width of that tag from the initial widht of the container div.

I don't know if that's the way it's done here, but it seems a nice approach.